# Html Css image hover opacity change and text appear without text opacity changing too?

Tags: html, css, image, opacity

I want it so that when I hover over the image the text appears the same way I have it except its opacity is unchanged.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/guineapig101/UEtLJ/

html:

```
<a class="img1"><p class="hoverText">yoooo</p></a>
```

css:

```
html,body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: #000;
}

p{
color: #fff;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: arial, arial black, italic;
}
.hoverText{
text-align: center;
visibility: hidden;
position: relative;
}
.img1{
position: absolute;
background-image: url('http://animalscamp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Grizzly-Bear-       3.jpg');
top: 0px;
left:0px;
width: 30%;
height: 40%;
}
.img1:hover p{
visibility: visible;
z-index: 9000;
}
.img1:hover{
cursor: pointer;
opacity: 0.6;
-webkit-transition: opacity;
-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-delay: initial;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}
```

Comment: You cannot affect the opacity of a background image..you would have to use an actual image in the HTML. Time to restructure.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot affect the opacity of a background image..you would normally have to use an actual image in the HTML but rather than an an unsemantic extra element purely for styling purposes you can manage this with a pseudo element like so.

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UEtLJ/6/)

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   background-color: #000;
}

p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: arial, arial black, italic;
}
.hoverText{
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.img1:hover .hoverText{
    visibility: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.img1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 40%;
}
.img1:before {
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url('http://animalscamp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Grizzly-Bear-3.jpg');
    transition:opacity.5s ease;
}
.img1:hover:before {
    opacity:0.6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need another element to put the image in, so that the text is not inside the element that you set the opacity on:

HTML:

```
<a class="img1"><span></span><p class="hoverText">yoooo</p></a>
```

CSS:

```
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   background-color: #000;
}

p{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: arial, arial black, italic;
}
.hoverText{
    text-align: center;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.img1{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:0px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 40%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.img1 span {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('http://animalscamp.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/Grizzly-Bear-3.jpg');
}
.img1:hover p{
    visibility: visible;
    z-index: 9000;
}
.img1:hover{
-webkit-transition: opacity;
-webkit-transition-property: opacity;
-webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-delay: initial;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
-webkit-transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.img1:hover span {
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UEtLJ/3/